# Disabling wallet during building bitcoin node

Tags: bitcoin

Why do we need to do ./configure --disalbe-wallet --with-gui=no during installing or building bitcoin node?

I was trying to build it whithout --disable-wallet but the configure throws the error

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to build bitcoin core with the `--disable-wallet` option. If you're having build errors without `--disable-wallet` then it's likely you don't have the BerkeleyDB library in your installation. It would help if you could post the related error.